# Check to see if a duplicate cookie exists on a specific subdomain?

Tags: cookies, asp-classic, vbscript

I'm trying to figure out how to delete the cookie without writing a session cookie every time through this vbscript.

We have two cookies, the first was set on the domain the website was running on with

```
response.AddHeader "Set-Cookie","cookie1=value;expires=Sun, 18-Jan-2037 00:00:00 GMT;path=/"
```

this set the domain to a.sitename.com. For a new release we set the cookie to the primary domain.

```
response.AddHeader "Set-Cookie","cookie1=value;expires=Sun, 18-Jan-2037 00:00:00 GMT;domain=sitename.com;path=/"
```

I need to delete the cookie on the `a.sitename.com` domain without deleting the one on the `sitename.com` domain.

I figured out that I can set the cookie to expire before today and it will be cleaned up at the end of the session.  But I don't want to drop a new cookie to expire at the end of the session every time through this code.

```
If( some check here ) then
  response.AddHeader "Set-Cookie","cookie1=value;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT;path=/"
End If
```

What's the best way in vbscript for checking to see if a cookie exists on a specific subdomain, while there exists a cookie with the same name and value on the root domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to realize that the browser is going to sandbox certain functionality and data for security purposes. Thus, it does not tell you in the HTTP request which domain the cookie is set to. It simply sends only the cookies to your server that the browser believes is valid for the request and then you only see the cookie name and value.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. "some check here" simply doesn't have that information server-side.

The browser knows which cookies is going to send, based on the domain the user is browsing. However, the cookie header sent to you doesn't contain that information.

Some suggestions:

- use a different cookie name
- if you can't change the cookie name, make sure the data stored in the cookie is somehow backwards compatible to the old value and you'll be able to gracefully handle both 'formats' of your data
- A special case I encountered recently: my production cookies ( mysite.com ) were interfering with my test cookies ( test.mysite.com ). My solution was to create a custom HOSTS entry for my test environment and access it as test-mysite.com so that there's no cookie clashing.

Hope this helps.